# Count number of times word occurs in text file

Tags: python, parameters, text-files

I am trying to create a function that will take 2 parameters: the name of a text file and a word to be searched from within the file. I would like the function to return the number of times each word occurs in the text file.

```
def countWord(txt, w):
    acc = 0
    for line in infile:
        if w in line:
            acc = acc + w
    return(acc)
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. This is a Question and Answer site. You've not explained a problem or asked a question, so at this point it appears you're just sharing what you want to do. Please see [ask], and then come back and [edit] your post to properly format your code, explain the problem you're having with it, and ask a **specific question** about the code. You'll also want to add a tag for the language you're coding in while you're editing; it helps you get it to the attention of those who can help more quickly.

Answer (score 0):

Hi i'm also new to python, here is my answer,

```
def countWord(txt, w):
          a=open(txt)
          word=a.read()
          return word.count(w)
countWord('file.txt', 'hello')
```

here,
'file.txt' is a file and 'hello' is search world.

i hope it will helps.

thanks,